# Is `UIStatusBarStyle` equatable?

Tags: ios, enums, integer, raw-types, equatable

I'm using a struct containing a property of type `UIStatusBarStyle` and like to use the "auto equatable feature" of Swift 4.1 for this struct.

The documentation of `UIStatusBarStyle` shows it's an enum of type int, but doesn't say "conforms to Equatable". Is it equatable? Are there any docs for this?

Comment: do you want to use the default feature? Check this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle

Answer (score 0):

> You can rely on automatic synthesis of the Equatable protocol’s
>   requirements for a custom type when you declare Equatable conformance
>   in the type’s original declaration and your type meets these criteria:
>
> - For a struct, all its stored properties must conform to Equatable.
> - For an enum, all its associated values must conform to Equatable. (An enum without associated values has Equatable conformance even
>     without the declaration.)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable